# How to get the machine learning model permutation Importance into an array or dictionary in python

Tags: python, permutation, random-forest

I have this code sample, that works well when I try this in `jupyternotebook`. And it shows as a table (an image) with two columns as below for the below code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

import eli5
from eli5.sklearn import PermutationImportance

X = inputsdf
y = targetdf
X_traindf, X_testdf, y_traindf, y_testdf = train_test_split(inputsNew, target, random_state=0)

estimator = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=2, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_traindf, y_traindf)


perm = PermutationImportance(estimator, random_state=1).fit(X_testdf, y_testdf)
eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X_testdf.columns.tolist())
```

[image]

**But I need these values to be converted as an array or dictionary or anything that I can assign to variable/s and re-use them. so it will look like kind of below:**

```
{
"PercentageSalaryHike": "0.0960 +- 0.0222",
.
.
.
}
```

**Can someone please help me? OR IS THERE A BETTER WAY TO FIND THE PERMUTATION IMPORTANCE FOR EACH COLUMN?**

Comment: you can use list bro.

Comment: Can you give an example on how to do that? @GHOST5454

Answer (score 0):

```
variable = np.array(eli5.show_weights(perm, feature_names = X_testdf.columns.tolist()))
```

**I hope this will work.**

Comment: No it doesn't output. It gives this warning/error: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/eli5/formatters/html.py:235: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  rel_weight = (abs(weight) / weight_range) ** 0.7
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`